# Sending a file over a TCP/IP socket (web server)

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm writing the barebones of a web server, but I can't figure out why my file isn't be sent over my socket, I'm connecting to it and everything it just not `send()`ing my file... What am I missing?

**//CODE** (server.c)

```
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/stat.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    

int main(void) {    
   int create_socket, new_socket;    
   socklen_t addrlen;    
   int bufsize = 1024;    
   char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);    
   struct sockaddr_in address;    

   if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0){    
      printf("The socket was created\n");
   }

   address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
   address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
   address.sin_port = htons(80);    

   if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){    
      printf("Binding Socket\n");
   }

    long fsize;
    FILE *fp = fopen("index.html", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    char *msg = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(msg, sizeof(msg), 1, fp);

   while (1) {    
      if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
         perror("server: listen");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen)) < 0) {    
         perror("server: accept");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if (new_socket > 0){    
         printf("The Client is connected...\n");
      }

        recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
        printf("%s\n", buffer);    
        write(new_socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
        write(new_socket, "Content-length: 46\n", 19);
        write(new_socket, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
/*      write(new_socket, "<html><body><H1>Hello world</H1></body></html>",46); */
        if((send(new_socket, msg, fsize+1, 0)) > 0){
            printf("success");
        }     
        else{
            printf("failed");
        }
      close(new_socket);    
   }    
   close(create_socket);    
   return 0;    
}
```

**//FILE** (index.html) *same directory

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't being sent?

Comment: its not even sending a response in the browser...

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this "barebones" server, it is not funny. You are not doing very good error handling. You are opening the file in text mode instead of binary mode. `sizeof(msg)` is wrong, use `fsize` instead (for that matter, I wouldn't advise reading the entire file into memory anyway, read and send it in chunks instead otherwise you won't be able to handle large files later on). You are calling `listen()` too many times, call it once, not in a loop. You are not checking if `recv()` failed...

Comment: ...  You are not trying to parse the client's request for correctness at all before sending your reply. You *must* use `\r\n` instead of `\n` in your reply headers. Your `Content-length` header is not specifying the *actual* `fsize` value (the file is *not* 46 bytes). You are not making sure `send()` is successfully sending *all* requested bytes. And sending `fsize+1` bytes is wrong, since the file is only `fsize` number of bytes. And there is no `Connection: close` header being sent.

Comment: who said it was funny... I just stated  I left errors out for clarity, I added them a minute ago....

Comment: @JordanDavis No you didn't. You just added success reporting. There is practically no failure handling in this code whatsoever.

Comment: so clearly this guy doesn't know what he is doing ---- http://blog.manula.org/2011/05/writing-simple-web-server-in-c.html

Comment: @JordanDavis: clearly, he doesn't.  The code is *completely* wrong for a dozen different reasons..

Comment: @RemyLebeau good to know...

Comment: can either of you guys show me a good example using `send()` you guys clearly no what your talking about lol

Comment: @JordanDavis Again, I had already done so.

Comment: @JordanDavis: I just posted an example.

Comment: Perfect thank you @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is *completely* broken, for a dozen different reasons.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>    
#include <sys/stat.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <unistd.h>    

bool writeDataToClient(int sckt, const void *data, int datalen)
{
    const char *pdata = (const char*) data;

    while (datalen > 0){
        int numSent = send(sckt, pdata, datalen, 0);
        if (numSent <= 0){
            if (numSent == 0){
                printf("The client was not written to: disconnected\n");
            } else {
                perror("The client was not written to");
            }
            return false;
        }
        pdata += numSent;
        datalen -= numSent;
    }

    return true;
}

bool writeStrToClient(int sckt, const char *str)
{
    return writeDataToClient(sckt, str, strlen(str));
}

int main(void){
    int create_socket, new_socket;    
    char *buffer;
    int bufsize = 1024;    
    struct sockaddr_in address;    
    socklen_t addrlen;    

    buffer = (char*) malloc(bufsize);    
    if (!buffer){
        printf("The receive buffer was not allocated\n");
        exit(1);    
    }

    create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (create_socket == -1){    
        perror("The socket was not created");    
        exit(1);    
    }

    printf("The socket was created\n");

    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));    
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
    address.sin_port = htons(80);    

    if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == -1){    
        perror("The socket was not bound");    
        exit(1);    
    }

    printf("The socket is bound\n");    

    long fsize;
    FILE *fp = fopen("index.html", "rb");
    if (!fp){
        perror("The file was not opened");    
        exit(1);    
    }

    printf("The file was opened\n");

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1){
        perror("The file was not seeked");
        exit(1);
    }

    fsize = ftell(fp);
    if (fsize == -1) {
        perror("The file size was not retrieved");
        exit(1);
    }
    rewind(fp);

    char *msg = (char*) malloc(fsize);
    if (!msg){
        perror("The file buffer was not allocated\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fread(msg, fsize, 1, fp) != 1){
        perror("The file was not read\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("The file size is %ld\n", fsize);

    if (listen(create_socket, 10) == -1){
        perror("The socket was not opened for listening");    
        exit(1);    
    }    

    printf("The socket is listening\n");

    while (1) {    

        addrlen = sizeof(address);
        new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen);

        if (new_socket == -1) {    
            perror("A client was not accepted");    
            exit(1);    
        }    

        printf("A client is connected from %s:%hu...\n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));    

        // I will leave it as an exercise for you to implement
        // a proper HTTP request parser here...
        int numRead = recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);
        if (numRead < 1){
            if (numRead == 0){
                printf("The client was not read from: disconnected\n");
            } else {
                perror("The client was not read from");
            }
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%.*s\n", numRead, buffer);    

        if (!writeStrToClient(new_socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")){
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }

        char clen[40];
        sprintf(clen, "Content-length: %ld\r\n", fsize);
        if (!writeStrToClient(new_socket, clen)){
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }

        if (!writeStrToClient(new_socket, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n")){
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }

        if (!writeStrToClient(new_socket, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n") == -1){
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }

        //if (!writeStrToClient(new_socket, "<html><body><H1>Hello world</H1></body></html>")){
        if (!writeDataToClient(new_socket, msg, fsize)){
            close(new_socket);
            continue;
        }

        printf("The file was sent successfully\n");
        close(new_socket);    
   }    

   close(create_socket);    
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: VG but you've ignored the return value of `fread()`, and you're calling `perror()` if `read()` returns zero, which isn't valid.

Comment: I am not ignoring the return value of `fread()`, but you are right about the return value of `recv()` (I am not calling `read()`). I have fixed that.

Comment: I have made some tweaks to the code.  Try compiling it again.

Comment: Where's `getaddrinfo()`?

Comment: @Pilpel: not needed in this example since it is hard-coded to use only IPv4 and listen only on `INADDR_ANY`. Using `getaddrinfo()` would produce the same `sockaddr_in`, unless you enable IPv6, in which case you need to allocate multiple sockets with multiple bindings, then `getaddrinfo` makes sense. Or you could just create a dual-stack socket to handle both IPv4 and IPv6 together, in which case you wouldn't use `getaddrinfo` again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought getaddrinfo was a must

Comment: @Pilpel: it *can* be used server side, but it is more useful on the client side

Answer (score 1):

```
fsize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
char *filebuff = malloc(fsize + 1);
```

Why `fsize+1`? You don't need the `+1`.

```
fread(filebuff, sizeof(filebuff), 1, fp);
```

Unchecked return value. The second argument should be `fsize`. At present you're only passing the `sizeof` the pointer.

```
//create/bind socket
if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0)
{    
  printf("The socket was created\n");
}
```

If the socket creation fails you must (a) print a proper error message as described below and (b) ***not*** just continue with execution as though the error hadn't occurred.

```
if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0)
{    
  printf("Binding Socket\n");
```

}

Ditto.

```
//listen, create new_sock, write headers, send file 
while (1){   
   if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
       perror("server: listen");    
       exit(1);    
    }
```

The `listen()` call should be ahead of the loop, not inside it. This is the first time you've actually handled a failure case.

```
    new_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen);            
    recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Invalid. Unchecked return code. The buffer is only valid at all if `recv()` returned a positive integer, and only that many bytes of it are valid. It should be:

```
    int count = recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
    printf("%.*s\n", count, buffer);
```

Then we start on HTTP:

```
    write(new_sock, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
    write(new_sock, "Content-length: 46\n", 19);
    write(new_sock, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
```

The line terminator in HTTP is inherited from Telnet and it is specified as `\r\n`, not `\n`.

```
    if(send(new_sock, filebuff, fsize+1, 0) > 0){
        printf("success");
    }     
    else{
        printf("failed");
    }
```

Inadequate. If you get an error from any system call, you must call `perror()`, or use `errno` or `strerror()` in an error message. "Failed" conveys no useful information, and debugging becomes a mere guessing game. Don't write code like this. You should use `perror()` or whatever you decide for all the other unchecked return values above.

But there is a bigger problem. You're assuming that the file fits into memory. There is no need for that assumption. Just copy the file using an 8k buffer as follows:

```
int count;
while ((count = read(in, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    send(out, buffer, count, 0);
}
if (count < 0)
{
    perror("send failed");
}
```

I would avoid `stdio` for this, it has too many issues, such as the poorly designed `fread()` and `fwrite()` function APIs.

Comment: I just updated my code adding in the values... I left the checks out for clarity, I had that written at the top of this question...

Comment: Thanks for you input @EJP

Answer (score 0):

Other then the wrong size used in various places (as noted by mathematician1975), your "real" problem is that your trying to communicate with a browser that expects an HTTP server.

**H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol is, well, [a protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). It is more complex then a simple connection and a dump of content.

You have to parse the request according to it, and send headers and content in a certain way.

Comment: Yea thats what I figured it was the headers.... will writing those on the socket first, before sending the file(index.html) work?

Comment: @JordanDavis read about the protocol. It's too long to be expressed in this answer, but there's plenty information online.

Comment: I know about the protocol I'm not a complete idiot :), and had the server working sending the html as a "string", but now when I try sending it as a file it's failing.. my guess is I need to send the headers to the socket before I send the buffer containing the html... or I need to write the headers to the buffer before I send the buffer?

Comment: Big picture, yes, headers come before content. But really, if you have any plan to be serious about this, read extensively about the protocol

Comment: writing it to the buffer(html) then send()..... or two send() operations one for headers, one for html.

Comment: @JordanDavis: TCP is a streaming transport. You can `send()` as many times as you need, the data will be buffered on the network layer as needed. What is important is *what* you send.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `bind()` is failing and report if so. You're binding to port 80; under Unix-like operating systems only root can bind to reserved ports (less than 1024).

Update 1:

You must initialize `addrlen` to `sizeof(address)` before calling `accept()`. From http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept:

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must
>   initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
>   to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
>   address.

Comment: I know its not this just because I had it working with a "string" of HTML before  hand, and the compiler isn't failing on the `bind()`