# C- HTTP web server accessed through web browsers

Tags: c, http, webserver

So we were asked to create a simple HTTP web server that can be accessed through the web browser (localhost:8080 for example).

I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char webpage[] = 
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html: charset-UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
        "<html><head><title>MP2</title>\r\n"
        "<stle>body (background-color: #FFFF00) </style></head>\r\n"
        "<body><center><h1> Hello World! </h1><br>\r\n"
        "<img src=\"doctest.jpg\"></center></body></html>\r\n";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int fd_server, fd_client;
    char buf[2048];
    int fdimg;
    int on = 1;

    fd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd_server < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =  INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    if (bind(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        close(fd_server);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(fd_server, 10) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        close(fd_server);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        fd_client = accept(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_len);
        if (fd_client == -1)
        {
            perror("Connection failed......\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Got client connection.......\n");

        if (!fork())
        {
            close(fd_server);
            memset(buf, 0, 2048);
            read(fd_client, buf, 2047);

            printf("%s\n",buf);
            if (!strncmp(buf, "GET /favicon.ico", 16))
            {
                fdimg = open("favicon.ico", O_RDONLY);
                sendfile(fd_client, fdimg, NULL, 4000);
                close(fdimg);
            }
            else if (!strncmp(buf, "GET /doctest.jpg", 16))
            {
                fdimg = open("doctest.jpg", O_RDONLY);
                sendfile(fd_client, fdimg, NULL, 6000);
                close(fdimg);
            }
            else
                write(fd_client, webpage, sizeof(webpage) - 1);
            close(fd_client);
            printf("closing....\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        close(fd_client);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And after entering "localhost:8080" in the browser, it opens a message tab that says "You have chosen to open *blank* which is text/html from http://localhost:8080"

The three files needed for this program to work: foo.c, doctest.jpg and favicon.ico is in one directory(Desktop). I don't know what to do with this error. Help is greatly needed and appreciated. This is my first time dabbling with web server codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem with the code but the http response and the html content send over the socket. You need to set the Content-Length: field also Connection: close tag. I don't have deeper understanding of HTTP protocol but you can get some info here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_responses.htm

I tried setting the webpage to below and the page was displayed (however since I didn't have the image file it was displayed as cross(x) )

```
char webpage[] = 
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-length: 194\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
        "<html><head><title>MP2</title>\r\n"
        "<stle>body (background-color: #FFFF00) </style></head>\r\n"
        "<body><center><h1> Hello World! </h1><br>\r\n"
        "<img src=\"doctest.jpg\"></center></body></html>\r\n";
```

This answer might also help [Sending a file over a TCP/IP socket (web server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749925/sending-a-file-over-a-tcp-ip-socket-web-server)

Note: In the above code I hardcoded Content-length value you should calculate it as per your html data.